# Why does adding an indeterminate JProgressBar to JTable kill the animation?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jprogressbar

I'm reverting a JavaFX UI to Swing.
In the UI, I have a table of tasks with progress bars.  When a task is of indeterminate length, I'd like to use an indeterminate progress bar.  Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to get an indeterminate progress bar to animate while inside the table.

GPT-4 has been very "helpful" in scouring this website to provide me all kinds of examples that don't work.

I've constructed an example below.  It draws a UI with an animating indeterminate progress bar.  Every 5 seconds, it adds a bar to the table -- alternating between a new bar and the one animating at the top.

Nothing animates in the table.  What's more, if I add the bar from the top to the table, it stops animating at the top as well.

What is going on?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestSwing extends JPanel implements TableCellRenderer
{
    String[] header = {"Progress"};
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(null, header) {
        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
            return getValueAt(0, col).getClass();
        }
    };
    JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
    JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar();

    public TestSwing()
    {
        bar.setIndeterminate(true);
        TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
        columnModel.getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(this);
        
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(bar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        return bar;
    }
    
    protected void update()
    {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (Exception e) {};
            EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
                tableModel.addRow(new Object[] {Boolean.TRUE});
            });
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                TestSwing list = new TestSwing();
                f.add(list);
                f.setSize(new Dimension(300, 500));
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
                
                Thread updater = new Thread(() -> list.update(), "List Updater");
                updater.setDaemon(true);
                updater.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This question has appeared a few times on this site:
I tried updating the table model as suggested by one accepted answer.
I tried redrawing the table as suggested by another.
I even tried having the TableCellRenderer return a different bar for indeterminate rows as the accepted answer of a third.

Finally, in constructing this toy problem, I realized that once added to a table, even a functioning indeterminate bar would stop animating.

If this works on your VM, do let me know what you're using.  It's not working on any of mine.

Comment: Because a table cell is a snapshot (or rubber stamp) rendering of the component, they aren’t live components

Comment: Also, Swing is NOT thread safe, meaning that any updates to the ui or state the UI relies on should be done from the context of the event dispatching thread

Comment: Personally, I’d question the value of doing this (showing an indeterminate progress bar in a table) and would maybe consider showing a “status” value instead, but that’s me

Comment: True: The JTable itself only shows a snapshot of the components inside.  This is why an animated GIF appears to hold still in a JTable.  However, you can tell a JTable to keep repainting a cell with a GIF in it, and the animation will work.  This is not so with an indeterminate progress bar.  No matter how many times you redraw the cell, the animation is frozen in time.

Comment: Yes, I tried this and it didn't work, I suspect it has to do with who the progress bar works (ie needing to be realised on the screen/on an active component) and the cells are shared, so if you had more then one progress bar, they'd all be in sync, which might not be what you want

Comment: At this point, I would settle for all the indeterminate rows being in-sync!

Comment: The animation of the progress bar is based on an internal timer (from memory) and it's state my be related to the components viewability (ie been attached to hierarchy which is realised on the screen, ie attached to a native peer) which is optimised to not animate the indeterminate state when it's not otherwise renderable on the screen. Looking at `BasicProgressBarUI` it uses `if (progressBar.isDisplayable()) {` to determine if should start the animation or not. In this case you might be forced to implement your own `ProgressBarUI` which can provide you some more control to update the state

Comment: I was hoping not to have to dig into that nest of private functions, but after doing so, I found a minimalist solution; thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BasicProgressBarUI employed by the JProgressBar has a handler that will stop the animation timer every time the component changes place in the hierarchy.  Since this is many layers of private classes and functions, and the hierarchy will be changed constantly by the TableCellRenderer, the easiest thing to do is override the behavior of the bar itself:

```
JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar() {
    @Override
    public boolean isDisplayable() {
        return table.isDisplayable() || super.isDisplayable();
    }
};
```

Comment: Props to @MadProgrammer for confirming that I had to wade in to that mess.

Comment: For posterity:  This only prevents the JProgressBar from ceasing its animation.  If you want to see it animate in the JTable, you will still have to tell the table to repaint that cell at the desired frequency!

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand the code you posted.

I went ahead and created this GUI.

[image]

In general, you create the GUI first, then you modify the state of the GUI.  Never, ever use a `Thread.sleep` in a Swing GUI.  Always use a Swing `Timer`.

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

Here's the code I came up with.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class JProgressBarTests implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JProgressBarTests());
    }

    private int listIndex;

    private JProgressBar[] list;

    public JProgressBarTests() {
        this.listIndex = 0;
        this.list = new JProgressBar[10];
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JProgressBar Tests");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createProgressPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                list[listIndex]
                        .setIndeterminate(!list[listIndex].isIndeterminate());
                listIndex++;
                listIndex = listIndex % list.length;
            }
        });
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();
    }

    private JPanel createProgressPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Progress");
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
        for (int index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
            list[index] = new JProgressBar();
            innerPanel.add(list[index]);
        }

        panel.add(innerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return panel;
    }

}
```

Comment: The Thread.sleep is not in the GUI, it's in another thread that occasionally pokes the GUI by putting something on the EventQueue, but I take your point.

Thank you for looking at the problem, but I'm afraid it doesn't address the issue:  An indeterminate JProgressBar stops animating if it's in a JTable.

Comment: @Pragmataraxia: As others have commented, you can't have an animated `JComponent` in a `JTable`.  If the animation is important, you can create your own `JPanel` using a `GridLayout` or a `GridBagLayout`.

Comment: You can tell a JTable to keep repainting a cell with an animated GIF in it, and you will see the animation proceed. This is not so with an indeterminate progress bar. No matter how many times you redraw the cell, the animation is frozen in time.  The bar itself stops animating, and I have failed to find a work-around besides "make your own ProgressBarUI".